# Embedding JavaScript into an AJAX partial response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it considered bad practice to embed javascript into partials returned via AJAX?

Let's say that on http://mysite.com, I have a button that gets a form via AJAX.
 Now let's say that I want to add some javascript event handlers to this form using jQuery (for validation and such).

The current ways to do this seem to be:

- In the AJAX callback that returns form, I can setup event handlers
  for the  tag.

I don't like this approach because it puts code that controls my form in two places: in the partial being rendered, and in the global javascript file(s) being included.

- Instead of returning a form from the server side, do everything client side. When a response from the server is required (for example, to validate the form), return JSON from the server, and create the resulting HTML elements (things like error messages) in JavaScript.

Now this approach makes me feel as though, I'm using JavaScript to create HTML elements instead of using more powerful server side tools (template languages) to do it.

I feel like the solution involves embedding JavaScript code into the HTML returned by the AJAX partial, so that it's an independently functional component of my application, and all the code is in one place.

Is there a cleaner way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: If you are just generating form html on the server-side, why waste time with a full HTTP request when you could easily embed a javascript template and do it all client side?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the argument can be made today that javascript is somehow inferior in terms of "power" when compared to other back-end languages... I think maybe because today **javascript is a valid back-end language**?

I think the second option makes sense because you're containing client/interface code, and segregating server-side logic for data manipulation and presentation.

There are plenty of javascript template libraries that work very well in my opinion, that is if you don't want to go the full [**javascript MVC**](http://javascriptmvc.com/) route.